# sub view are not adjusted while rotating from portrayed to land scape mode

Tags: iphone

i did an application that supports for both portrayed and landscape modes.

totally it contains 5 views.

at 4 button click events i add 4 view as subview to the main view.

when ever i rotate view from portrayed to land scape only main is adjusted but remaining 4 sub views are not adjusted,they will appear 3/4 of the screen width portrayed mode.

can i adjust all the view along with main view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any subviews will not be rotated automatically except the main view. Even so, everything in the main view will remained unrotated. You need to apply transforms to all of them when the device detects an orientation change.

Comment: can u please suggest how can i transform sub views